# Is it necessary to manually rebuild a sendmail.cf file or is this done automatically on service restarts?

Tags: centos, sendmail

CentOS 5.x | SendMail

I'm noticing inconsistent information regarding pushing changes from sendmail.mc

Some documentation suggests that making changes to the sendmail.mc file requires two steps:

1. Rebuild the cf file: `m4 /etc/mail/sendmail.mc > /etc/mail/sendmail.cf`
2. Restart sendmail service

Other documentation suggests that the rebuild process is already done as part of a service restart.

Can I get confirmation on if step 1 is required?

---

Update: If I grep for make in the init script, the output shows:

```
[root@foo ~]# grep make /etc/init.d/sendmail
        if test -x /usr/bin/make -a -f /etc/mail/Makefile ; then
          make all -C /etc/mail -s > /dev/null
                makemap hash /etc/mail/$i < /etc/mail/$i
        if [ -x /usr/bin/make -a -f /etc/mail/Makefile ]; then
          make all -C /etc/mail -s > /dev/null
                makemap hash /etc/mail/$i < /etc/mail/$i
```

Comment: Well...look in the service startup script.  You're on CentoS 5, so this will probably be `/etc/rc.d/init.d/sendmail`.  Does it rebuild the configuration when you start the service?

Comment: It is always to safe to manually make (or m4) the sendmail.mc file into the sendmail.cf file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In CentOS you do:

```
/etc/mail/make
service sendmail restart
```

You also need to have package `sendmail-cf` installed.  A simple restart does not rebuild the .cf from the .mc.

However (and I am looking at a CentOS 6 machine) the init script calls the routine `updateconf` upon starting sendmail, so there in 6.x you only restart.  What is the out put of

```
grep make /etc/init.d/sendmail
```

in your machine?

In Debian `sendmailconfig` rebuilds the .cf if needed before restarting it.

Comment: Looks like there are make statements in there. Updated info in the question to include this.

Comment: So if you change .mc and then type `make all` does it build the .cf? If yes, then it rebuilds on restart. The easiest way to check all this of course is to `touch /etc/mail/sendmail.mc` wait 10 seconds and then `service sendmail restart`. Then `ls -l /etc/mail/sendmail.*` and check the dates.

Comment: Yup. The dates match so it would appear that the cf file is automatically updated in my case. Sorry - I guess that was an obvious way to check but I didn't know if the `make` command was adding additional content.

Answer (score 0):

You need to rebuild to generate the new config and restart to apply the configuration.

Comment: In general, I think think that's probably the established/accepted procedure but in my specific case I don't think it's necessary because I can see the make statements in the init script.